# How to import a deployed jar "SNAPSHOT" from local Artifactory repository into another project?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I am a newbie in Artifactory, I have 2 projects one depends on another...
I set up Artifactory on a server and deploy the first jar into libs-snapshot....and change the C:\Users.m2\setting.xml and add this tag in the pom of the deployed project:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>serverId</id>
            <name>serverName</name>
            <url>serverUrl/artifactory/libs-snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

how can I access the first project from the second one via Artifactory repository
I am working on Netbean8.2, glassfish 4 and artifactory 4

Answer (score 1):

By default, maven doesn't know to look anywhere except your local repo and maven central. You'll need to tell it the additional repos it can look in either via a pom setting or settings.xml.

You can see some example and additional details in the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).

Comment: what if I got the setting.xml generated by the artifactory and replaced with the one on m2 and also add the distributionmanagment tag to the pom file...what is else?!

Comment: make sure netbeans is using the correct maven settings.xml and that the second project has the required dependencies on artifacts from the first project

Comment: should i add dependency at the second project!  so what is the benefit of artifactory repository, I though I just add the distributionmsanagment tag in both project to link them with the repository!

Comment: I think I miss the linkage part,,,could you clarify in steps...I correctly install the artfactory and configure the setting.xml, also i am able to deploy a jar to the local repository and update the pom file....what is next! what do i miss...

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة `<distributionManagement>` only determines where `mvn deploy` will upload your project, not where it should look to find other dependencies. If you look through the link, you'll see the `<repositories>` examples that are what you'll need to add to link to your remote repo.

Comment: if you please write them in order and in steps,,,I feel i got confused and couldn't find the issue!